# Apply same format to different cell with different input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know, if possible, how can the following be done: I have two cells with different inputs that change depending on filters.

Example:

```
A1 = 5
A2 = 7
```

`A1` has a dynamic format that changes depending on its value.

The value of `A2` also changes, however I would like to have the same cell color and font as `A1` despite not having the same number.

Copy formatting is not an option as it is static. 
Apply same formatting rules does not do the work as it has different values.

Maybe a macro that copies format of `A1` to `A2` every time change in value happens.

thanks in advance,

Kylian

Comment: How is `A1`'s format set, conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the same conditional formatting to multiple cells:

To create a new rule:

1) Highlight `A1:A2`

2) Add a new rule with the following formula:

```
$A$1=5
```

(I assumed 5 is the value that triggers the rule)

To expand an existing rule, go to Conditional Formatting and edit the formula so it uses absolute referencing (i.e. add `$` in front of the column and row: `$A$1` instead of `A1`, then edit the range the rule applies to:

[image]